# Disable parallax on mobile with stellar

Tags: mobile, parallax

i have a problem,

i would like to disable the parallax effect on my website when he is on a mobile device, so i looked on different forum, and i found this code :

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if( !isMobile.any()){
    $(window).stellar();
    }
});
```

But that didn't work, there is no way to disable stellar with a simple code ?

(i find a another code to detecte the device)

```
if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
{
console.log('You are using a mobile device!');
}
else
{
console.log('You are not using a mobile device!');
}
```

this one works (with the .js).

But i still dont know how to disable stellar.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Following your first example change the last part with this:

```
if( !isMobile.any() )
$(function(){
    $.stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: false,
    verticalOffset: 50
    });
});
```

For me it worked well, the statement says: "If NOT mobile then initialize Stellar".

Note that the list of mobile agents you provided is not complete, it's for the majority of devices tho, but keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me;

```js
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};



jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 

      jQuery(window).stellar({ 
   horizontalScrolling: false,
   hideDistantElements: true,
   verticalScrolling: !isMobile.any(),
   scrollProperty: 'scroll',
          responsive: true
   });
   
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.